# вопрос по QThreadPool

Tags: c++, qt

Использую `QThreadPool`, делаю `setMaxThreadCount(10)`, ошибок нету, все работает, только потоков в тредпуле все равно 4(количество ядер на машине), понять совершенно не могу, почему. Кто сталкивался с таким и как решали проблему?

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, ну ставлю setMaxThreadCount(10), в итоге потоков максимум 4+1 все равно получается

Comment: Может просто не нагружаете нормально тредпул?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setMaxThreadCount` устанавливает максимальное кол-во потоков, которые может использовать 'QThreadPool'.  'activeThreadCount' покажет кол-во потоков, которые используются прям сейчас. Создавать сразу много потоков нет смысла. Но если Вы создадите достаточно заданий, может быть 'QThreadPool' и создаст их. Но тут опять же все сложно - если задачи работают с сетью/диском и медленные, то много потоков может быть оправданно. Если же задачи тяжелые (кодирование видео, биткоины, перебор паролей), то кол-во потоков по кол-ву ядер оптимальное. Увеличение кол-ва потоков не даст прироста.

Для дальнейшего понимания, почитайте о [законе Амдала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Comment: да я сделал сервер "нить на соединение", нити берутся из пула, однако после 4 нити все: пятое соединение вроде установлено, однако обмена нету, закрываешь одно соединение - и это пятое становится активным, можно принимать/посылать данные... использую QTcpSocket

Comment: В этом случае Вам не нужен QThreadPool - он не предназначен для этой задачи. Ваши задачи "слабонагруженные" - поэтому и не создаются дополнительные потоки.

Comment: хм, а как он определяет когда надо создавать а когда не надо доп. поток?

Comment: я думаю, что нужно залазить глубоко в код и смотреть. Как костыль Вам может помочь [reserveThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthreadpool.html#reserveThread). Но это костыль.